# Why is nomath option not working with stix2?

Tags: stix2

This might just be me not knowing how to usepackage but `\usepackage[nomath]{stix2}` is (I think) not letting the package work, eg mathbb isn't defined, and `\usepackage[nomath=true]{stix2}` says undefined option. Am I misunderstanding the "Do not change the default math fonts" option? I just want the capital psi to look the same as in usual math mode, and not the stix version.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which TeX engine you employ: pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, something else?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using pdfLaTeX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stix2` options do not take values `[nomath=true]` is incorrect.

`[nomath]` prevents the package loading math fonts, so you get the standard math fonts, so `\mathbb` is undefined unless you load some package such as `amsfonts` that defines it.

You can of course load the original cm font and access its Greek if you wish but I wouldn't advise it, stix and computer modern are not intended to be visually compatible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmoperators}   {OT1}{cmr} {m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmGamma}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmDelta}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmTheta}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmLambda}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmXi}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmPi}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmSigma}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmUpsilon}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmPhi}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmPsi}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmOmega}{\mathalpha}{cmoperators}{"0A}
\begin{document}

$ \Phi + \cmPhi + \emptyset + \varnothing + \Psi + \cmPsi $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, in that case is there a way I can keep the stix2 option and just get the capital psi looking the usual way?

Comment: @Lulu surely you want all Greek to come from the same font? Just changing one character would look weird, you can of course, but....

Comment: @Lulu I added some code

Comment: Thanks! I'm not used to seeing different fonts so I didn't realise that it looks weird, I'll take your advice and keep them all the same.